# WPF (vb.net) Text from web page to label/text block

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to read and display a text from my HTML Page into a Label or TextBlock in my WPF application. How do I do that?

With Windows Forms I have done it this way:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Webseite\test.htm")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim ImageInhalt As String
    Label1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mytext").GetAttribute("value")

    ImageInhalt = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mytext2").GetAttribute("value")

    If ImageInhalt.Contains("STOP") Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._stop
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

HTML Page (test.htm)

```
<input type="text" name="userInfoNav" value="Hallo"/><br/>"
```

Many thanks now for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load the HTML content of an URL or file into a `mshtml.HTMLDocument`. You can then process the DOM object in a JavaScript like syntax.

Requires reference to *Microsoft.mshtml.dll*.

**C#**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private mshtml.HTMLDocument HtmlDocument { get; set; }

  public async Task SetTextBoxTextAsync(string filePath, string id)
  {
    await UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(filePath);
    string value = GetHtmlElementValueById(id);
    this.TextBlock.Text = value;
  }

  private async Task UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(string filePath)
  {
    string htmlContent = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);
    this.HtmlDocument = new HTMLDocument();
    (this.HtmlDocument as IHTMLDocument2).write(htmlContent);
  }

  private string GetHtmlElementValueById(string elementId)
    => this.HtmlDocument.getElementById(elementId).innerText;
}
```

**VB.NET**

```vb
Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Private Property HtmlDocument As mshtml.HTMLDocument

    Private Async Function SetTextBoxTextAsync(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal id As String) As Task
        Await UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(filePath)
        Dim value As String = GetHtmlElementValueById(id)
        Me.TextBlock.Text = value
    End Function

    Public Async Function UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(ByVal filePath As String) As Task
        Dim htmlContent As String = Await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath)
        Me.HtmlDocument = New HTMLDocument()
        (TryCast(Me.HtmlDocument, IHTMLDocument2)).write(htmlContent)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHtmlElementValueById(ByVal elementId As String) As String
        Return Me.HtmlDocument.getElementById(elementId).innerText
    End Function
End Class
```

### Remarks

If you are interested in rendering the content, then use the [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) control. It has a `Document` property that you can cast to a `mshtml.HTMLDocument`. Since the `WebBrowser` is a heavy instance, you should only use it if your intend is to render the HTML. Otherwise constuct the `mshtml.HTMLDocument` manually like shown above.